# Open a link from a webview in a chrome app within the same webview

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a chrome kiosk app that will open a webpage that contains links in a webview and then load the links within the same webview. However, the links on the webpage that I am working with are `target="_blank"` and I am getting the error `<webview>: A new window was blocked` wehn they are clicked. I found a solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428668/how-to-open-a-new-window-from-a-link-in-a-webview-in-a-chrome-packaged-app) and tried to implement its suggestion like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
chrome.app.window.create(
'window.html',
{ 'width': 1000, 'height': 1000 },
function(win) {
  win.contentWindow.onload = function() {
    var webview = win.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#webview');
    webview.addEventListener('newwindow', function(e) {
    chrome.app.window.create(e.targetUrl,window.open()
    });
  };
  }
 );
});
```

However, I would like to have the link open not in the browser, but in the same webview that the link was launched from.

Is there some way to capture the target URL, strip it of its `target="_blank"` attribute, and then load the URL in the original webview?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323263/open-a-link-from-a-webview-in-a-chrome-app-within-the-same-webview) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799892/how-to-launch-a-new-window-in-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An event listener in the content script will capture the URL when the `newwindow` event is fired. Once the URL is captured, it's a simple thing to set the URL as the webview's source.

```
var webview = document.querySelector('#webview');
webview.addEventListener('newwindow', function (e) {
    //prevent the link from attempting to open a new window        
    e.preventDefault(); 
    webview.src = e.targetUrl;
});
```

Because this script doesn't open any new windows, it doesn't have to be run specifically in the app's background script.